# In the PowerShell grammar, what is the the `lvalueExpression` rule saying?

Tags: parsing, powershell, grammar, ebnf

I was reviewing the PowerShell grammar posted here: http://www.manning.com/payette/AppCexcerpt.pdf

(I don't think it has been updated since PowerShell v1, and there are some typos. So, it's clearly not the **true** PowerShell Grammar, but a human-oriented document.)

In section C.2.1, it says:

```
<lvalueExpression> = <lvalue> [? |? <lvalue>]*
```

What is the meaning of the question marks? I can't tell if it means "match any character" or "match a question mark" or it's a typo.

I'm not sure what inputs this is intended to match, but maybe it's this:

```
$a,$b = 1, 2
```

in which case maybe the question mark is supposed to be a comma?

Comment: The actual grammar can be found in the [PowerShell Language Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9706). The one in Payette's book also has a few errors.

Comment: Version 3 of the grammar can be found here:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36389

Comment: It's stunning how many errors and omissions are in Payette's grammar.  Clearly he never tried to implement his own grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Based on its use in the preceding rule (`<assignmentStatementRule> = <lvalueExpression> <AssignmentOperatorToken> <pipelineRule>`), it appears that `lvalueExpression` in [Appendix C](http://www.manning.com/payette/AppCexcerpt.pdf) of [Windows PowerShell in Action](http://www.manning.com/payette) corresponds to `expression` in section **B.2.3** of [The PowerShell Language Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9706) that [Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11958941#comment15936543_11958941) linked to. Matching it further than this is difficult, but I'll add some speculation anyway :)

The `?` characters in `[? |? <lvalue>]*` are very likely erroneous. If it had been used to represent "the previous token is optional", then:

- the `[` and `|` tokens it was applied to should have been quoted
- only `[` makes sense as part of a value expression, but indexing is already covered later by the `propertyOrArrayReferenceOperator` rule
- `?` is not used anywhere else in the grammar, but `{0|1}` *is* used multiple times to indicate "can appear zero or one times"

Given its similarity to `[ '|' <cmdletCall> ]*` at the end of the first rule in the section, it may have been a copy-and-paste error, compounded by a ‘smart quote’ round-trip encoding error. Assuming this was copied with the intent of editing later, then `?|?` may have become `'.'` to represent multiple property accesses (but again, this is covered by the `propertyOrArrayReferenceOperator` rule).

Though based on the statement at the end of section **C.2.1** that "[the pipeline rule] also handles parsing assignment expressions", `lvalueExpression` was probably intended to list all the assignable expressions besides `simpleLvalue` (e.g. `cast-expression` for `[int]$x = 1`, `array-literal-expression` for `$a,$b,$c = 1,2,3`), etc).